# Returning a value from a function with move semantics or the return value optimization, but not the copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a good way to return a value from a function in C++ where we guarantee that the copy constructor is not called?  Either the return value optimization or the move constructor are fine.  For example, with the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
private:
    // Disallow the copy and default constructor as well as the assignment
    // operator
    Foo();
    Foo(Foo const & foo);
    Foo & operator = (Foo const & foo);

public:                         
    // Store a little bit of data
    int data;                   
    Foo(int const & data_) : data(data_) { }

    // Write a move constructor 
    Foo(Foo && foo) {           
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
        data=foo.data;          
    }                           
};                              

// Write a function that creates and returns a Foo
Foo Bar() {                     
    Foo foo(3);                 
    return foo;                 
}                               

// See if we can mix things up  
Foo Baz(int x) {                
    Foo foo2(2);                
    Foo foo3(3);                
    return x>2 ? foo2 : foo3;   
}                               

int main() {                    
    // This is using the return value optimization (RVO)
    Foo foo1 = Bar();           
    std::cout << foo1.data << std::endl;

    // This should make the RVO fail 
    Foo foo2 = Baz(3);
    std::cout << foo2.data << std::endl;
}
```

We have a compiler error

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++11 test01.cpp -o test01
test01.cpp: In function 'Foo Baz(int)':
test01.cpp:10:5: error: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)' is private
test01.cpp:35:25: error: within this context
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

since the copy constructor is private.  Now, if we modify the Baz function to

```
// See if we can mix things up
Foo Baz(int x) {
    Foo foo2(2);
    Foo foo3(3);
    return std::move(x>2 ? foo2 : foo3);
}
```

we do in fact run correctly.  However, this seems to preclude the RVO from being used ever.  Is there a better way to structure these functions if we must guarantee that the copy constructor is not called?

Comment: Have you tried `= delete` instead of marking the ctor private?

Comment: Automatically moving objects is only done when copy-elision (aka (N)RVO) is applicable but not performed. In your case, copy-elision (which also encompasses moves, btw) is not applicable because you don't have `return name;`. You can restructure your code to that form by substituting the conditional-operator with a simple `if`(/`else`), though. [See this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6656ad6214923e1)

Comment: @xeo elision can only occur if the same variable is returned everywhere I thought: is that just a implememtation restriction I have internalized?

Comment: @Yakk: Implementation restriction. That's one of the cases where it is "applicable but can't be performed", what I mentioned above. :) Another would be *assigning* to another variable, instead of constructing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, your example is addressed in [n1377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Copy%20vs%20Move):

> With this language feature in place, move/copy elision, although still
>   important, is no longer critical. There are some functions where NRVO
>   is allowed, but can be exceedingly difficult to implement. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> A
> f(bool b)
> {
>     A a1, a2;
>     // ...
>    return b ? a1 : a2;
> }
> ```
>
> It is somewhere between difficult and impossible to decide whether to
>   construct a1 or a2 in the caller's preferred location. Using A's move
>   constructor (instead of copy constructor) to send a1 or a2 back to the
>   caller is the best solution.
>
> We could require that the author of operator+ explicitly request the
>   move semantics. But what would be the point? The current language
>   already allows for the elision of this copy, so the coder already can
>   not rely on destruction order of the local, nor can he rely on the
>   copy constructor being called. The auto-local is about to be
>   conceptually destructed anyway, so it is very "rvalue-like". The move
>   is not detectable except by measuring performance, or counting copies
>   (which may be elided anyway).
>
> Note that this language addition permits movable, but non-copyable
>   objects (such as move_ptr) to be returned by value, since a move
>   constructor is found and used (or elided) instead of the inaccessible
>   copy constructor.

Their example of solving this (in favor of move semantics) is:

```
// Or just call std::move
// return x>2 ? static_cast<Foo&&>(foo2) : static_cast<Foo&&>(foo3);
return static_cast<Foo&&>(x>2 ? foo2 : foo3);
```

> The logic resulting from this implicit cast results in an automatic
>   hierarchy of "move semantics" from best to worst:
>
> ```
> If you can elide the move/copy, do so (by present language rules)
> Else if there is a move constructor, use it
> Else if there is a copy constructor, use it
> Else the program is ill formed
> ```

Or as Xeo mentions, you can structure it this way:

```
Foo Baz(int x) {                
    Foo foo2(2);                
    Foo foo3(3);                
    if (x > 2)
        return foo2;
    else
        return foo3;
}
```

You already provided an example in the OP, but the standard provides one for eliding the move/copy constructor (it equally applies):

```
class Thing {
public:
    Thing() { }
    ~Thing() { }
    Thing(Thing&& thing) {
        std::cout << "hi there";
    }
};
Thing f() {
    Thing t;
    return t;
}
Thing t2 = f();
// does not print "hi there"
```

But if you supply both the move and copy constructor, the move constructor seems to be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

From the C++ standard:

> [class.copy]/31: When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. ... This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-
>   unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

Since `x > 2 ? foo2 : foo3` is not the name of an automatic object, copy elision is not permitted.